# recursively checking conjunctive normal form

Tags: recursion, racket, conjunctive-normal-form

I am using Dr Racket to check if an expression passed is in Conjunctive normal form.

The code checks if the expression is in Negative normal form first.

```
(define (is-nnf? expr)
  (cond
   [ (is-constant? expr) #t ]
   [ (is-variable? expr) #t ]
   [ (is-not? expr) (is-variable? (op1 expr)) ]
   [ (is-or? expr) (and (is-nnf? (op1 expr)) (is-nnf? (op2 expr))) ]
   [ (is-and? expr) (and (is-nnf? (op1 expr)) (is-nnf? (op2 expr))) ]
  ) 
)
```

is-nnf checks recursively whether the expression is in negative normal form.

I am trying to write a similar expression named is-cnf to recursively check if an expression is in conjunctive normal form.

> is-constant -> checks if the expression is  a constant (Eg #t, #f)
>
> is-variable -> checks if the expression is  a variable (Eg 'a, 'x)
>
> is-not -> checks if the first element of the list is a 'not ( Eg.
> '(not x))
>
> is-or -> checks if the first element of the list is a 'not (
> Eg. '(or x y))
>
> is-and -> checks if the first element of the list is a
> 'not ( Eg. '(and x y))